# Separate the words of a text by a special character " , "

Tags: php, string, forms

I have a question

I get a text by `input[type="text"]` look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="tags"/>
```

I received an string value that looks like this:

```
$tags = $_POST['tags'];
$tags = "car,BMW,speed,fast";
```

I need Separate the words by "," and add to `$arr` look like this :

```
$tag_arr = ['car','BMW','speed','fast'];
```

How can I do it !?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=split+string+by+character+php or https://www.google.com/search?q=split+string+by+character+php

Answer (score 0):

Use "explode" function present in php. Like below

```
$tags = explode(",","car,BMW,speed,fast");
```